# How to get the resolution of screen? For a WinRT app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to know the screen resolution so that I can set the height of an element according to the resolution in a Windows 8 app.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

How about this?

```
var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;

double height = bounds.Height;

double width = bounds.Width;
```

Comment: Use this.  Don't assume you are in the primary screen as done in Md's answer

Comment: This doesn't get the screen size, only your window size. If you are running snapped it will be incorrect. If all you need is the window size this will work.

Comment: it is now a double, not an int.

Comment: does anyone know how to do this in c++/cx? using the suggested way gives the error "Bounds is not a member of Window".

Comment: It gives current size of the app windows not the system, if may produce false results when screen is in snapped view

Comment: This only gives you the app Window Size, NOT the screen resolution.

Answer (score 13):

Getting the bounds of current window is easy. But say if you want to set a large font size for bigger screen (resolution is same as 10" device, but screen is 27"), this wont help. Refer [Scaling to different screens](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx)
I used the following method to detect screen size & change text block font style appropriately.

```
         void detectScreenType()
    {
        double dpi = DisplayProperties.LogicalDpi;
        var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
        double h;
        switch (ApplicationView.Value)
        {
            case ApplicationViewState.Filled:
                h = bounds.Height;
                break;

            case ApplicationViewState.FullScreenLandscape:
                h = bounds.Height;
                break;

            case ApplicationViewState.Snapped:
                h = bounds.Height;
                break;

            case ApplicationViewState.FullScreenPortrait:
                h = bounds.Width;
                break;

            default:
                return;
        }
        double inches = h / dpi ;
        string screenType = "Slate";
        if (inches < 10)
        {
            screenType = "Slate";
        } else if (inches < 14) {
            screenType = "WorkHorsePC";
        }
        else 
        {
            screenType = "FamilyHub";
        }
        ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        localSettings.Values["screenType"] = screenType;
    }
```

Comment: This gives size of the window, not full screen size, unless running in full-screen mode.

Answer (score 6):

Probably the best option for DirectX-enabled apps, however, applicable to all other kinds of metro apps is:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2012/07/24/get-screen-resolution-in-windows-8-metro-style-application.aspx

P.S. C'mon, getting window size to determine screen resolution? What about snapped/filled modes? This world is so much broken :-/

Comment: Height does not change in snapped/filled modes ;)

Comment: And thanks. Anyways, I made it to work without setting the height. :)

Answer (score 3):

apparently i don't have enough rep to reply to posts yet, but in regards to @Krishna's answer, it may be worth noting that his solution requires:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
```

probably not an issue for most of you, but in my case (trying to grab resolution of executing app from an imported library), it wasn't there by default.

hope this helps someone else...

Comment: There is no Windows.UI.XAML package available. how can i use it ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using XAML? If so it does not matter. Use the Grid control. It will fill up all available space. Read [Jerry's blog](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/05/windows-8-why-i-choose-xaml-metro-over.html) as to why you might want to use xaml for WinRT development.

Comment: I have two rows, one with height 70 and another with *. I have a textBox which is in the second row. I want to the textbox to change it's height according to resolution.

Comment: by default a TextBox style will fill the entire area it is given. This is the Silverlight style, but should still apply, or you can assign this style http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28v=VS.95%29.aspx