# Get window width / height in Windows store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I currently have a basic page which loads, and I need some way of obtaining the width and height of the window, preferably in the constructor. The problem is, in the constructor, or before the page is completely loaded, I can't seem to get hold of the width and height. After it is loaded I can just use:

```
this.ActualWidth;
this.ActualHeight;
```

Is there any window load complete event I can use or any way to obtain the width and height during the loading?

Comment: They aren't calculated until the control is rendered.  I don't know off-hand if there is a way to get them in code in metro.  In WPF I think you can just handle the `OnResize` event or some such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the resolution of screen? For a WinRT app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828179/how-to-get-the-resolution-of-screen-for-a-winrt-app)

Comment: @ptf you can set the preferred launch size if that helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find out the size of the Window at any moment using the property [Window.Current.Bounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.bounds). For more details, read: [How to get the resolution of screen? For a WinRT app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828179/how-to-get-the-resolution-of-screen-for-a-winrt-app)

Comment: I'm was also relying on this value. But I'm getting weird values. When I select 10.6" 1366 x 768 these the Bounds are set to: (0, 0, 1371.429, 771.429). So it appears as if the width and height are increased by 3.5 pixels!? This is also happening on the actual device (Surface HD)

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/19/getting-the-most-out-of-your-pixels-adapting-to-view-state-changes.aspx) is a blog post on how to handle the `SizeChanged` event.  You can't get the ActualWidth/ActualHeight without doing something like this because they are calculated when the control is rendered.

```
private void OnWindowSizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var CurrentViewState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value;
    double AppWidth = e.Size.Width;
    double AppHeight = e.Size.Height;

    // DownloadImage requires accurate view state and app size!
    DownloadImage(CurrentViewState, AppHeight, AppWidth);
}

Window.Current.SizeChanged += OnWindowSizeChanged;
```

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("w:{0} h:{1}", width, height);