# Get Screen Size in Windows8 C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, screen-size

Is there a way to get the screen size in inches of a Windows 8 (C#) Screen? I know that I can get the resolution but I can't find a way to know if the screen is a 4" screen or a 7", or even a 10" screen.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does this help you?
Window.Current.Bounds
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899121/get-window-width-height-in-windows-store-apps

Comment: Why do you want to get screen size ? What is your requirement ?

Comment: Hi There, I need the screen dimensions (in inches, cm,mm, etc). I know how I can do to get my screen resolusion but I can't get my screen size.