# How to get the screen resolution in WinRT JavaScript app?

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, screen-resolution

No duplicate of [get screen resolution winrt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828179/how-to-get-the-resolution-of-screen-for-a-winrt-app)

Above is possible in C# etc. but not in JavaScript.

SO how can I get screen resolution in a JavaScript WinRT app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the `window` object and get the width and height:

```
var width = window.outerWidth;
var height = window.outerHeight;
```

Keep in mind that, while the WinJS stuff in WinRT apps doesn't translate back to the web browser platform, anything on the web browser platform *should* translate directly into WinRT apps.  So any approach for getting the window's dimensions in a browser should work in the WinRT app as well.