# How can I get actual screen resolution, not window size, in Windows 8.1 app?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I have pretty simple problem, I want to know how to detect in Windows 8.1 Store app the **actual screen resolution**, not the effective pixel size and not the current window size.

There is lot of guides around for finding the current window size, but these guides cannot be used if the app is resized to half of the screen, or in snapped mode, or running in free window on Windows 10.

My use case for this is to offer different available video streams on different screen sizes, 1080p stream should not be offered if user has only 1024x768, etc.

Comment: This is already [well covered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828179/how-to-get-the-resolution-of-screen-for-a-winrt-app), don't use the top answer.

Comment: I've seen that question, the accepted solution covers only current window size.

Comment: @MartinSuchan Consider using this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11954960/3994425

Comment: Hmm, that's probably the best solution now. If you place it as answer, I'll mark it as solution.