# Get screen resolution for UWP

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone, uwp

[this is what I tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936154/get-screen-resolution-in-win10-uwp-app)
doesn't give the right height.

 What I did?

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
```

before

```
        var bounds = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds;
        var scaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
        var size = new Size(bounds.Width * scaleFactor, bounds.Bottom * scaleFactor);
        ScreenSize = size;
```

and save the screensize in a setting for that device during first run and let the app work in default window from then onwards. 
This works perfectly in my laptop and my Lumia 1520 with hardware buttons. 
Doesn't on Lumia 640XL with on-screen taskbar.

 I need the exact resolution, Is there a way I can get that done?

Answer (score 0):

You can get height on phone like difference of visible top and visible bottom (if you are in portrait mode):

```
double visibleHeight=ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds.Bottom - ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds.Top;
```

and difference of visible left and right positions in landscape mode:

```
double visibleWidth=ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds.Right- ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds.Left;
```