# How to get screen size of monitor in multi-monitor setup in UWP C#

Tags: uwp

I am using below C# code to get the screen size of the monitor in UWP.

```
var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
var screenSize = new Size((int)displayInformation.ScreenWidthInRawPixels,
                                      (int)displayInformation.ScreenHeightInRawPixels);
```

But the problem is it returns first monitor resolution. I have two monitors and I need to screen size of the monitor where the app is run. not first monitor. If the app runs on the second monitor then I need screen size of the second monitor instead of the first monitor. My monitor size is different.

How can I solve this puzzle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Screen Resolution in Win10 UWP App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936154/get-screen-resolution-in-win10-uwp-app)

Answer (score 0):

That should actually be the behavior you will be getting - once you move your app to another screen, `DisplayInformation` properties will start returning values for that given screen.

I have tested it locally as well - you don't even have to get a new instance via `GetForCurrentView` - even if you just have one instance, calling `ScreenWidthInRawPixels` and similar properties when your app moves to the second screen, you will be getting the correct values.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I need to set app size while app is load. so like if screen resolution is 1600x 900 then I need to set app size 400x400 and if screen resolution is 1280x1080 then I need to set app size 300x300.

Comment: That should be fine still - `DisplayInformation` should return the correct values according to the screen the app launches on